# Using ASP.NET with no models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a single web page that will do calculations using a class library I created. It has 80 or so calculation methods across 10 classes. This class library doesn't have properties. It has classes with methods that have parameters.

I can populate a view with the text boxes I need using reflection. Here's a screen shot:
[Vogels Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bil1W.png)

Here's the code I'm using to create the formula in the screen shot:

```
    @using OpticianMathLibrary;
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    @*Here's where I'm getting the type and method*@
    @{ Type myType = (typeof(BaseCurve));}
    @{ var myMethodInfo = myType.GetMethods();}
    @{ var aMethod = myType.GetMethod("VogelsRulePlus");}


   @*This is what creates the formula and text boxes*@
   <h1>Formula:</h1>
   <h2>@aMethod.Name</h2>

   @*Creates text boxes with parameters*@
   @{ var methodParameters = aMethod.GetParameters();}

   @{ foreach (var param in methodParameters)
    {
        <h3>@param.Name</h3>
        @Html.TextBox(param.Name)

    }}
    <br />
    <br />

    @*Temporary values to give the method actual parameters*@
    @{ var sphere = 1.00;}
    @{ var cylinder = -1.00;}

    @*Method being created by reflection*@
    @{ var invokeMethod = aMethod.Invoke(aMethod, new object[] { sphere, 
    cylinder});}

    @*Button to invoke the method*@
    <input type="button" value="Calculate"  
     onclick="document.getElementById('result').innerText = @invokeMethod" 
     /> 

     @*Label to show the results*@
     <h1 id="result"></h1>
```

I realize that I'm using a specific class "BaseCurve" and a specific method "VogelsRulePlus". Eventually, those values will actually come from a drop down at the top of the form or something like that.

My question is, how do I hand the forms text box data back to the controller? The number of parameters will usually be different based on what the method needs.

Also, where do I invoke the method I created with reflection? In the controller or the view?

Am I doing too much in the view?

Is the way I'm going about this just generally hosed?

By the way, this is my first asp project. I've only used winforms up until now.

Thanks,
R

Comment: Yes, your doing too much in the view. And this does not really make sense. The c# code runs on the server, so you need to either have a form and make a normal submit to a POST method, or make and ajax call to a controller method that does your calculation and return the result back to the browser.

Comment: How do I make the form dynamically like I need to?  Do I perform the reflection in the controller and somehow tell the view to make the text boxes and "labels"?

Comment: Why are you using reflection? Just pass a model to the view. The code you using cannot ever bind correctly to anything, nor can get any validation.

Comment: Which model? The classes in my .dll? I don't have models with properties per se. I have static classes that have static methods and parameters. I'd like to dynamically create data entry fields at run-time based on the method signatures. After I create the fields to enter the values (numbers in my case because these are all math methods) I want to invoke the method with those values as the parameters. Then of course display the result.

Comment: Create a view model with the properties you need in the view and pass it to the view

Comment: Ok. I think I'm confused now. Create a view model with the properties you need in the view and pass it to the view? How do I create a view model in the view with properties, when it's not concrete what method (from .dll) I'll need until run time? Do I just create one giant model that could have every property possible? If so, how do I correlate the view model with method parameters?

Comment: All you have shown is one view with 2 properties. I cant guess what others you might have. You said you need a dropdownlist to select the 'class', so you view model will at least contain a property to bind the selected value to and an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property for the options. You could then handle its `.change()` even to load a partial view based on the selected option. As for the calculated result, you either need to call the server to return it, or write javascript functions to calculate the result in the browser.

Comment: Ultimately, I think my understanding of ASP.NET MVC 5 is what needs the most attention here. I've made a couple of working examples using standard methods and, as my knowledge becomes adequate, I'll move into the fancy stuff. I think I'm trying to approach this problem like it's a Winform when it's not.  I really appreciate your help Stephen and, if I get to a worthy solution, I'll post it back (pun intended) here and show you what I came up with.